# Can fontspec temporarily change a feature for a specific font on the fly?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

## Question

After setting up fonts in the preamble with

```
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\newcommand{\fontspath}{/path/to/fonts/}
\setmainfont[% AGaramondPro
    Path = \fontspath ,
    Extension = .otf ,
    UprightFont = *-Regular ,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
    BoldFont = *-Bold ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
]{AGaramondPro}
\newfontfamily\dejavu[% DejaVu Sans
    Path = \fontspath ,
    UprightFont = *-Regular ,
    BoldFont = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic
]{DejaVuSans}
```

Can you change a feature on the fly when calling a new font like on page 16 of the [fontspec manual](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)?

## Example

I want to change the BoldFont feature in Deja Vu Sans from *-Bold to *-Boldoblique.

## Sample Code

Something like the following:

```
\section{\dejavu\addfontfeature{BoldFont = *-Boldoblique} Test}
```

Comment: Define a new font family, it's easier. It would be even easier using a package such as `titlesec` for defining the format of titles.

Comment: Ok. The section command was just an example. It could appear anywhere in the body too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, provided you properly define the font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\dejavu[% DejaVu Sans
    Extension = .ttf,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Oblique,
]{DejaVuSans}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\dejavu\addfontfeature{BoldFont = *-BoldOblique}Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]